# Can I execute a cURL call from postgres trigger

Tags: php, database, postgresql, triggers, database-trigger

I have to create a process call on a db field(s) being a certain status. I have heard you can execute a cURL call with a db trigger but Google is not being kind enough to return anything I can use.

So I guess my question is three parts:

1. Can this be done?
2. Reference?
3. Alternative Solution?

Workflow:

db field is updated with status, need to kick off script/request/process that run the next step in my work flow (This is a PHP script) that will pull the recorded in the db and process another step, then update the db with the results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You shouldn't use triggers for that, as a trigger blocks transactions so it will make your database very slow. Also you'd need to install unsafe language to Postgres — pl/sh, pl/perl, pl/python or other.

There are 2 better solutions for this problem:

- have a process which connects to database and [LISTEN](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-listen.html)s for [NOTIFY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-notify.html) events generated by your trigger — this will work instantly;
- periodically check for new data using, for example, a cron script - this would work with a delay.

Comment: Thanks for the insight but a delay wont due, need instantaneousness

Comment: So listen/notify is your answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you can call a shell script, 
http://plsh.projects.postgresql.org/
you can call a curl.

But I get a creepy feeling about the approach...

- If the remote server goes offline, data inconsistency??

Alternative:

- I wouldn't put business logic in triggers, only customized constraints or denormalisation.
- Do what you need to do with either middle-tier, or stored procedures.

Regards,
//t

Comment: The script call just kicks off the process instantaneousness which pulls the data from the database. This could be done at a later time but would like the fastest return possible.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is a trigger in postgres that will run the necessery script. Triggers are explained in [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/interactive/triggers.html), the syntax for adding a new trigger is explained [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/interactive/sql-createtrigger.html). The trigger type you're looking for appears to be an AFTER UPDATE trigger. As far as I know, the script you run will have to check if the field is of the required status, as postgres will always run the trigger.

Comment: This looks interesting, I will have to explore this more. Bonus as you can write the trigger in C