# How to notify row changes of rds mysql version 5.6.4?

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, binlog

I need to monitor row changes of 5 tables of an ancient MySQL instance - version 5.6.4.

I know that aurora has lambda_call function, so I could combine this function with triggers and get what I need. But, is there a similar solution for this old mysql instance?

Could I read binlog? If so, is there a library (python, node, golang...) to parse this file? Something that I can deploy to ecs and consume those files. Also, remember, I need for 5 tables.

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271812/can-i-execute-a-curl-call-from-postgres-trigger) if it helps.

Comment: @Kaneki21 That's PostGres, not MySQL.